# Наибольшее значение из двух массивов

Tags: массивы

Язык - Питон. Привет!
Делаю игру покер Техасский холдем. Столкнулся с проблемой сравнивая двух флэшей. Если у двух игроков два флэша, то нужно сравнить у кого из них флэш старше. Для этого я брал ранки флэша и записывал их в отдельный массив, полученные значения складывал между собой и суммы из двух массивов сравнивал между собой. Так было до того, как я встретил такую комбинацю, где флэш слабее имел сумму ранков выше, чем флэш старше. Пример:

```
array1 = [12, 0, 2, 3, 4]
array2 = [11, 10, 2, 3, 4]
```

По правилам покер побеждает array1, так как у него туз (12), а сумма значений выше у array2.

Попробовал также брать только максимальное значение из двух массивов, но это тоже не подходит, так как разницу могут составлять небольшие значения, например:

```
array1 = [12, 11, 10, 5, 6]
array2 = [12, 11, 10, 3, 4]
```

Не могу придумать алгоритм. Помогите пожалуйста, кому не трудно. Спасибо.

Comment: То есть выигрывает тот, у кого самая старшая карта. А если старшие одинаковы, то выигрывает тот, у кого больше сумма карт. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Если честно, если бы я ответил на этот вопрос, то я бы уже, наверно, нашёл решение :)))
По идее тот, у кого туз во флэше, тот и побеждает. А вот мой код написан не так.
В общем, да, у кого туз, тот и победитель. Но как же быть тогда со второй ситуацией, где решают небольшие ранки?

Comment: То есть нужно сравнить старшие карты на соответсвие друг другу и делать разницу на младшие карты? Или как?

Comment: Вначале у меня находятся два флэша, потом идёт сравнение по пяти картам, у какой комбинации сумма всех ранков выше, тот и победил, но это ошибочное решение, как вышло.

Comment: https://artandpoker.ru/kak-opredelit-starshij-flesh/ , здесь говорится, что сначала нужно сравнить старшие, а если они одинаковы, то идти слева направо. Как только наталкиваемся на различные - побеждает тот, у кого старше

Comment: По правилам же выигрывает тот флеш, где старшая карта больше? Разве нет?

Comment: Вот с вики: Так, A♠ 9♠ 7♠ 3♠ 2♠ будет старше, чем K♠ Q♠ 9♠ 7♠ 3♠. Если старшие карты одинаковы, сравниваются вторые по старшинству. Если одинаковы и они - третьи, и т.д. Если флеши одинакового достоинства, банк делится. Также банк будет делиться, если игроки собрали флеши одного достоинства, но разных мастей. Старшинства мастей в покере не существует.

Comment: Просто реализуйте этот алгоритм, и все. Это не вопрос по программированию, это вопрос по покеру

Comment: Спасибо, Мирон. Я про алгоритм и спрашивал. Так и сделаю

Comment: Ещё вопросик. Как сделать, чтобы было не прямое сравнение массивов, а получение значения? Чтобы на нескольких игроков были свои значения. Например, 25, 32, 41... А потом их сравнить и узнать, у кого больше.

Comment: Надо отсортировать по убыванию и рассмотреть как число, например шестнадцатеричное. У кого больше, тот выиграл.

Comment: У меня может быть 23 игрока. Пока выход сравнивать 23 массива между собой, по предложенному алгоритму. Но со стабильными значениями это было бы куда проще.

Comment: becouse, массив уже отсортирован по убыванию. А что дальше Вы предложили я не понял.
А понял, не получится наверно. Суммы могут быть разные, а туз может победить с меньшей суммой.

Comment: Я просто не стал выдавать победителя, чей массив больше, а стал прибавлять 100 очков к сумме, чей массив оказался больше при сравнении.

Answer (score 0):

Просто сортируешь массивы и проходишься по ним элемент за элементом.

````
def find_winner(handX, handY):
    handX.sort()
    handY.sort()
    for i in range(len(handX)):
        if handX[i] > handY[i]:
            return 'Hand X has won'
        if handY[i] > handX[i]:
            return 'Hand Y has won'
    return 'Draw'

array1 = [12, 11, 10, 5, 6]
array2 = [12, 11, 10, 3, 4]

print(find_winner(array1, array2))```
````

Comment: Спасибо сонак!!

Comment: просто стараюсь мотивировать людей задавать вопросы в правильных местах